# Replaceing a complete node in an existing xelement

Tags: c#, xelement

I have an xElement data `<a><item><item1/><item2/></item></a>`

Need to replace item node with another node .
How can we achieve this?
I just need to replace item node with some other node say `<b><b1/></b>`

I want output as `<a><b><b1/></b></a>`

Comment: please add some code on how youhave tried to do it

Answer (score 0):

you could use ReplaceWith

```
xelementnode.ReplaceWith(new XElement(yournode));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below script, this is help you to replace the node

```
XElement xmlTree = new XElement("Students",
    new XElement("Andrew", "Andrew Wilson"),
    new XElement("Thomas", "Thomas Alwa"),
    new XElement("Winston", "Winston GH"),
    new XElement("Hary", "Hary Potter"),
    new XElement("Jacky", "Jacky Elia")
);

XElement xel = xmlTree.Element("Winston");

xel.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Bill", "Bill Gate"));

Console.WriteLine(xmlTree);
```